# Wieso schreibt man "Numerus clausus" ohne Bindestrich?

Tags: spelling, compound, english, hyphen, latin

Wenn man englische Worte eindeutscht, werde diese entweder mit Bindestrich ("Economy-Class") oder als zusammengesetzte Worte geschrieben ("Economyclass") [1]. Wieso wird "Numerus clausus" getrennt geschrieben [2]? Gelten für Latein andere Regeln beim Eindeutschen, als für moderne Sprachen?

[1] https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Schreibung-von-Fremdwortern-aus-dem-Englischen

[2] https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Numerus_clausus

Comment: In meiner Erfahrung werden aus dem Englischen eingedeutschte Begriffe schon seit vielen Jahren weder mit Bindestrich noch zusammengesetzt geschrieben,sondern mit dem originalen Leerzeichen.

Comment: Aber ss heißt weder Joint-Venture noch Jointventure, sondern Joint Venture

Comment: Hier irrt der Duden. In der Sprachpraxis habe ich noch nie "Economy-Class" oder "Economyclass" gesehen, sondern immer nur "Economy Class".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deine Frage beruht auf einer falschen Prämisse:

*Numerus clausus* ist im Latein ein Substantiv mit einem Partizip-Adjektiv und heißt wörtlich "geschlossene Zahl". Die grammatische Struktur ist also anders als bei englischen Konstruktionen, die sich im Deutschen als zusammengesetztes Substantiv widergeben lassen.

Wie [RHa](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/26847/rha) in einem Kommentar richtig anmerkt, sind Verbindungen zweier Nomen im Nominativ im Latein unüblich. Häufiger sind Genitiv-Nominativ-Verbindungen, wie etwa *Spiritus loci* ("der Geist des Ortes"), die auch im Deutschen auseinandergeschrieben werden.

Comment: Wie sieht es bei anderen Ausdrücken lateinischer Herkunft wie 'bona fide'  oder 'nolens volens' aus? Gerade bei ersteren zieht das Argument doch nicht (oder ist mein Latein zu eingerostet)?

Comment: @planetmaker Meins ist auch eingerostet, aber ich denke "bona fide" müsste Ablativ sein von "bona fides", guter Glaube, das ist also auch ein Substantiv mit Attribut. "Nolens volens" sind auch zwei Wörter, die nebeneinander stehen (nichtwollend wollend). Aus dem Englischen: "Smart Home" wird (im Gegensatz zu "Smartcard" und "Smartphone") auch meist getrennt geschrieben. Wie man sowas ins Deutsche übernimmt, scheint schon auch Moden unterworfen zu sein.

Comment: Verbindungen zweier Substantive im Nominativ sind im Lateinischen äußerst unüblich. Häufig wird eins davon in den Genitiv gesetzt, z.B. "Genius loci". Verbindungen von Nominativ und Genitiv werden auch im Deutschen getrennt geschrieben.

Comment: Interessant, dass die Arten des Eindeutschen von Wörtern wie Smartphone oder Smart Home aus der heutigen lingua franca und auch von Worten anderer Sprachen einem gewissen Laisser-faire unterliegen ;)

Comment: @RHa Danke für den Hinweis, ich hab ihn in die Antwort übernommen.